# How can I prevent Dio from throwing an error after successfully retrying?

Tags: dart, dio

I'm using Dio to do requests to a REST-api. When the authorization token expires, I refresh the token and resend the request. The code to do that looks like this:

```dart
onError: (DioError error, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
logger.d(errorLogString(error));

if (error.response?.statusCode == 401 && error.requestOptions.path != 'login' && _retries-- > 0) {
  await authService.refreshToken();

  error.response = await dio.request(
    error.requestOptions.path,
    data: error.requestOptions.data,
    queryParameters: error.requestOptions.queryParameters,
    options: Options(
      method: error.requestOptions.method,
      headers: error.requestOptions.headers,
    ),
  );
}

return handler.next(error);
},
```

This works okay, but Dio still throws an error even if the new request is successful, which means that I have to catch and check the status code for each request. For example like this:

```dart
try {
  final response = await dio.post(
    'someUrl',
  );
  return Object.fromJson(response.data);
} catch (error) {
  if(error is DioError && (error.response?.statusCode ?? 300) < 300){
    return Object.fromJson(error.response!.data);
  }

  throw parseError(error);
}
```

Is there any way that I can prevent Dio from trowing an error at all when the request is successfull, or do I have to catch the error each time like I do above. In that case, is there a way to simplify the process of catching the error and returning the successful response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone else is looking for the answer to this like I was today, you can use handler.resolve(response)

Using the above example:

```
onError: (DioError error, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
logger.d(errorLogString(error));

if (error.response?.statusCode == 401 && error.requestOptions.path != 'login' && _retries-- > 0) {
      await authService.refreshToken();

      var response = await dio.request(
        error.requestOptions.path,
        data: error.requestOptions.data,
        queryParameters: error.requestOptions.queryParameters,
        options: Options(
          method: error.requestOptions.method,
          headers: error.requestOptions.headers,
        ),
      );
      return handler.resolve(response);
    }
    return handler.next(error);
},
```

Comment: Thank you. My solution was to implement my own Dio client, but this is clearly better. It's a good day when you can replace 60 lines of code with one. :)

Comment: One tip: Instead of crafting a new request manually, await dio.fetch(error.requestOptions) could be called directly.